# Uninstalling and Re-Installing homebrew on the Mac

Tags: homebrew

```
MacOS: Ventura 13.1
```

I have several packages on my Mac installed using Homebrew. I am dealing with a situation, following the update to Ventura 13.1, where the only solution may be to uninstall and re-install Homebrew.

What are my options, if I want to make sure all the tools/apps I installed using Homebrew are re-installed when the process is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
brew bundle dump
```

which creates a `Brewfile` of all your taps and packages, followed by:

```
brew bundle
```

which reinstalls everything you had before from the `Brewfile`.

Comment: I assume a file is created to retain the informatin, any idea where that would be created?

Comment: It's called `Brewfile` and is in the current directory- you can view it with `more Brewfile` or using `textedit` with `open -e Brewfile`